# SQL Insert command error

Tags: sql-server

```
Create table Loan
(
    LoanID Int,
    LoanAmount Decimal(5,2)
)

Select * from Loan

Insert Into Loan(LoanID, LoanAmount)
Values (1, 1555), (2, 7500), (3, 2455), (4, 8630), (5, 5685)
```

I'm not able to insert values into the table with data type `Decimal(5,2)`. It throws an error

> Arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric.
>   The statement has been terminated.

If I increase the precision value it works.

Can someone help out?

Thank you

Comment: No need to be so restrictive.  Disk space is cheap and SQL is fast.  Leave some room for larger loans.   For my loan systems, I've use the money type with no issues

Answer (score 2):

There is not an issue. Precision is the **total** number of digits that will be stored and scale is number of digits to the right of the decimal. So in your example you have 2 digits to the right of the decimal and a total of 5 digits meaning you could only have 3 to the left.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

Change it to `Decimal(6,2)` or even larger if you need to accommodate larger numbers.